# Greeting The User

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

Create a program which when run displays the text below:

```
)-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(
| Welcome User! |
)-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(
```

Use any functions or language to answer this, have fun. Shortest code wins

Comment: Can we alternatively return this from a function, as per usual?

Comment: Are leading/trailing newlines allowed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>41</s> 39 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Shaggy*

```
[U="){"-*-*-*^_"ê}("`| WelÖ  U r! |`U]·
```

### Explanation:

```
[U="){"-*-*-*^_"ê}("`| WelÖ  U r! |`U]·
[                                    ]    // Create a new array
 U=                                       // Variable U =
   ")                                     //   ")
     {            }                       //   Evaluate everything in curley-brackets as code
      "-*-*-*^_"ê                         //   "-*-*-*^_" mirrored -> -*-*-*^_^*-*-*-
                  ("                      //   ("
                                          * Now we have [U=")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-("]
                    `| WelÖ  U r! |`      // "| Welcome User! |" decompressed by `...`
                                     U    // ")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-("
                                          * Now we have [")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(","| Welcome User! |",")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-("]
                                      ·   // Split with new-lines
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/PzrUVkmzWklXCwTj4pUOr6rVUEqoUQhPzTk8TUEh9NCCIkWFmoTQ2EPb//8HAA)

Comment: [39 bytes](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=W1U9Iil7Ii0qLSotKl5fIup9KCJgfCBXZWzWICBVoHIhIHxgVV23&input=)

Answer (score 33):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 54 bytes

```python
print(")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(\n| Welcome User! |\n"*2)[:53]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EQ0lTVwsE4@LjwLSuRkxejUJ4ak5yfm6qQmhxapGiQk1MnpKWkWa0lalx7P//AA)

Comment: WOW, I'll tattoo this approach on my cerebral cortex!!

Comment: Impressive, beat me by 1 byte!  Take a +1

Answer (score 12):

## T-SQL, 60 bytes

```
PRINT')-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(
| Welcome User! |
)-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-('
```

SQL allows splitting string literals over lines, so those returns are counted.

Working on a procedural solution, but doubt I'll find one under 60.

**New Edit**: Found a simple `REPLACE` that ties the trivial solution:

```
PRINT REPLACE('1
| Welcome User! |
1',1,')-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(')
```

Turns out that `REPLACE` will do an implicit conversion of a numeral to a string, so this lets me save 2 characters by eliminating the quotes around my replacement character.

Trying to put it into a variable is too long, due to the overhead of the `DECLARE` (69 bytes):

```
DECLARE @ CHAR(17)=')-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-('PRINT @+'
| Welcome User! |
'+@
```

Comment: Please see this: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1146/46066

Comment: This answer is completely fine @juniorRubyist

Comment: Ok. I removed that downvote.

Comment: Thanks. Thought you were originally referring to the [hard-coding the output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1063/70172) limitation, but that's allowed for kolmogorov-complexity. Just not particularly efficient.

Answer (score 8):

### Python 2.7, 55 bytes

```
a="\n)-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(\n"
print a+'| Welcome User! |'+a
```

Pretty simple.  Includes leading and trailing newlines.

Comment: It does not need to be a function.

Answer (score 7):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>78</s> 75 bytes

```c
main(i){for(;printf(")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(")&i--;puts("\n| Welcome User! |"));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI1OzOi2/SMO6oCgzryRNQ0lTVwsE4@LjwLQuUEQtU1fXuqC0pFhDKSavRiE8NSc5PzdVIbQ4tUhRoUZJU9O69v//r3n5usmJyRmpAA)

Comment: Nice try, pretty low amount of bytes as well!

Comment: Lowest I have got it down to is 66 bytes so far

Comment: 71 bytes with a trailing newline (75 without): [`#define P puts(")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(")
f(){P;puts("| Welcome User! |");P;}`](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VIUChoLSkWENJU1cLBOPi48C0LlCEK01DszrAGiJfoxCempOcn5uqEFqcWqSoUKOkaR1gXfs/M69EITcxM09Dk6uaSwEIgJqsuWr/f83L101OTM5IBQA)

Comment: @Amurt4l if you would like, since you have gotten quite a few answers, you can post your own answer as well :)

Answer (score 7):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 43 bytes

```
00000000: d3d4 d502 c1b8 f838 30ad abc1 55a3 109e  .......80...U...
00000010: 9a93 9c9f 9baa 105a 9c5a a4a8 50c3 a589  .......Z.Z..P...
00000020: ae06 00bd 4d85 9835 0000 00              ....M..5...
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYwxDgJBCEV7T/FPMGGWxYB3MLGxsYOZXRst9/wjG43GR/iEQF5sEY/lvj3HoA8ndO4zutCEVkOxKiuYvMOjVYg4o5ItQHmjlHHNPrwNNR3mxrBmKyzc81881wyfXSHUGC5qX8ctq1x@jikdvtARRNExdxWYsmC/ZeCPXXAuRXKM8QI)

Comment: This language <s>is</s> feels like such an abuse of the "rules", that I think we should change them just so that @Dennis will have to change the language a little

Comment: @StephenS TBH, I agree. However, thankfully languages optimized for [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] (Jelly, 05AB1E, V, SOGL, some others) can still usually beat it without feeling as cheap.

Comment: @StephenS If a challenge is best solved with Bubblegum, it’s the challenge’s fault, not the language’s. Instead of rules lawyering, write more interesting challenges.

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>31</s> <s>29</s> 26 bytes

-3 Bytes thanks to [Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47066/emigna)

```
")-*-*-*^_".∞D”|‡Ý‚Ý! |”s»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fSVNXCwTj4pX0HnXMc3nUMLfmUcPCw3MfNcw6PFdRAciZW3xo9///AA)

#### Explanation

```
")-*-*-*^_".∞D”|‡Ý‚Ý! |”s»
")-*-*-*^_"                # Push )-*-*-*^_
           .∞              # Intersected mirror (results in )-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-( )
             D             # Duplicate top of stack
              ”|‡Ý‚Ý! |”   # Pushes | Welcome User! |
                        s  # Swap top items on stack
                         » # Join on newlines
```

Comment: You could do `.∞` instead of `û¨'(«`

Comment: I knew this had to exist somehow! Thanks man

Comment: Nevermind, what I posted was equivalent lol.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but you can save a byte by changing the `")-*-*-*^_"` to `')„-*Ð„^_J`. :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>32</s> 30 bytes

```
_^×*-³(⸿emocleW |‖Ｂ¬Ｊ¹¦¹ User!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREMpPk5J05oLwgnJzE0t1lDS0lXSUTDWhAsracQUpebmJ@ekhivUgFQHpablpCaXOJWWlKQWpeVUalgdWgMU9irNLQjJ1zDUUTBE6FUILU4tUgTq@v//v27Zf93iHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
_^              Print("_^");
×*-³            Print(Times("*-", 3));
(⸿emocleW |     Print("(\remocleW |");
```

Prints the mirror image of the top left portion of the output.

```
‖Ｂ¬             ReflectButterfly(:¬);
```

Reflects down and to the left to create the top and bottom lines and the left of the middle line.

```
Ｊ¹¦¹            JumpTo(1, 1);
 User!          Print(" User!");
```

Fixes up the middle line.

Comment: (Why the downvote?)

Comment: Apparently someone's been downvoting many of the answers in this challenge, my submission is also one of the affected ones.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, 56 bytes

```
alert(`${s=")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-("}
| Welcome User! |
${s}`)
```

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>50</s> 48 bytes (function)

```
_=>(s=")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(")+`
| Welcome User! |
`+s
```

-2 bytes thanks to Rick Hitckcock

Comment: Why `alert`? Save a few bytes using a function.

Comment: @Shaggy I know that, just edited it in, but currently OP says display, and has not responded to my comment yet

Comment: Please see this: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1146/46066

Comment: @juniorRubyist we usually allow either a complete program or a function. OP did not specify that functions that returned the value instead of displaying it were allowed, so my second two entries may not be allowed. However, complete programs are (almost) always allowed, and JavaScript doesn't need boilerplate. Copy my `alert` into a `.js` file and run it in your browser, it'll run.

Comment: Save 2 bytes with `_=>(s=")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(")+`\n| Welcome User! |\n`+s`

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the function argument instead of a new variable for storing the top and bottom of the string?

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, 62 bytes

```python
print(")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(\n| Welcome User! |\n)-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(")
```

Comment: Needs to be a function.

Comment: Please see this: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1146/46066

Comment: But it's not a snippet. It's a full program.

Comment: No, does not need to be a funciton. Read it again: **Use any functions or language to answer this.**

Comment: @juniorRubyist The 1st line of the question says `Create a program`

Comment: @dzaima I'll point out the [other python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127575/47990) and then direct you towards [the standard defaults](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6912/47990).

Comment: @dzaima this is actually a full program..

Answer (score 4):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 42 bytes

```
/#/)-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(
/#| Welcome User! |
#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/X19ZX1NXCwTj4uPAtK4Gl75yjUJ4ak5yfm6qQmhxapGiQg2X8v//AA)

Shorter than the Bubblegum solution!

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 4):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 55 bytes

```
22#)[#-#*]"^_^"[#*#-]#(V"
| Welcome User! |
"R!&@v&@R&@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@//fyEhZM1pZV1krVikuPk4pWllLWTdWWSNMiatGITw1Jzk/N1UhtDi1SFGhhkspSFHNoUzNIUjN4f9/AA)

It's 2 bytes shorter than hardcoding the output.

### Explanation

```
22                         Push 2 2s to the stack
                             These are used for loop counting
  #)                       Push )
    [#-#*]                 Push -* 3 times, using one of the 2s
          "^_^"            Push ^_^
               [#*#-]      Push *- 3 times, using the remaining 2
                     #(    Push (
                       V   Create a new stack
                        "
| Welcome User! |
"                          Push \n| Welcome User! |\n to the new stack
 R!&@                      Return to main stack, print entire stack without popping
     v&@                   Switch to 2nd stack, pop and print stack
        R                  Return to main stack, pop and print stack
```

Answer (score 4):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>56</s> 54 bytes

```
/a"| !resU emocleW |>"01pa
 l?!;o
/"(-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-)"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/Xz9RqUZBsSi1OFQhNTc/OSc1XKHGTsnAsCCRSyHHXtE6n0tfSUNXCwTj4uPAtK6m0v//AA)

2 bytes saved by AGourd

Comment: On your first line, you could change    |"a">"01p    to    |>"01pa    to save a couple characters

Comment: @AGourd; Oh I must have missed that, seems simple when you point it out :) - I'll edit it out soon, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 49 bytes

```perl
print$\=")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(","
| Welcome User! |
"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvRCXGVklTVwsE4@LjwLSuhpKOEleNQnhqTnJ@bqpCaHFqkaJCDZfS//8A)

Uses the fact that `$\` is implicitly printed after each `print`.

Comment: What about `say`?

Comment: @simbabque I tend to follow [this consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7539/55508). Furthermore, replacing all `print` with `say` isn't really where the point of golfing lies in my opinion. But I'm not on any crusade to stop using `say` though; I let everyone do as they like, and everyone is happy :)

Answer (score 3):

## C, 75 bytes

```
main(){char*S=")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(";printf("%s\n| Welcome User! |\n%s",S,S);}
```

Comment: 70 bytes like this;
`m=")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(";main(){printf("%s\n| Welcome User! |\n%s",m,m);}`

Answer (score 3):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 35 bytes

```
é)8a-*r(ãhR^_^Äo| Welcome User! |
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///BKTYtEXS3pIo3DizOC4uLjpA@35NcohKfmJOfnpiqEFqcWKSrU/P8PAA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: e929 3861 2d2a 1b72 28e3 6852 5e5f 5e1b  .)8a-*.r(.hR^_^.
00000010: c46f 7c20 5765 6c63 6f6d 6520 5573 6572  .o| Welcome User
00000020: 2120 7c                                  ! |
```

Explanation:

```
é)                          " Insert a '('
  8a                        " Append 8 copies of the following: 
    -*<esc>                 "   '-*'
           r(               " Replace the last character on this line with '('
             ãh             " Move to the middle of this line
               R            " And write the following text over the existing text:
                ^_^<esc>    "   '^_^'
                        Ä   " Duplicate this line
o                           " On a new line:
 | Welcome User! |          "   Write the whole middle line
```

Answer (score 3):

## **Pyth, 41 bytes**

It's boring, but I just cant find a way to creat `)-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(` or `| Welcome User! |` in less bytes than just copying the strings.

```
J")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-("J"| Welcome User! |"J

Explanation:
J")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-("                      # J = ")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-("
                    J                     # Print J with new line
                     "| Welcome User! |"  # Print "| Welcome User! |" with new line
                                        J # Print J with new line
```

[try it Online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J%22%29-%2a-%2a-%2a%5E_%5E%2a-%2a-%2a-%28%22J%22%7C+Welcome+User%21+%7C%22J&debug=0)

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 60 bytes

```cs
_=>")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(\n| Welcome User! |\n)-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-("
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY1RC4IwEMff/RTXnmakX8D0JeglgijCF1HGPGWgG2wrkPSzr2ZQQdHv4P7H3Q@Om4grjQ4e8I4ZAwetWs36wG9uc/cYy6zgcFWihj0Tkoav01vynAZjsY@3F8nXxmoh2xU8M4MGUlelGQmjpa@yKueMaCFHyLHjqkc4G9QLGAv5ZRGXBL9@bZQ0qsM418IibSghYZj8E4/I6h0O9MOa5mlydw)

Answer (score 3):

## Golang, 82 bytes

```
func main(){var a string=")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(\n";Printf(a+"| Welcome User! |\n"+a)}
```

[Try it online!](https://play.golang.org/p/sykG6Zz-__)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! Your submission can be a function that returns the text as output, as per meta consensus, which might make it shorter and better for this site.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you for the heads up. I'll make an edit.

Comment: You have to include the `fmt` import, sorry.

Comment: @totallyhuman wait but it's not part of the function.

Answer (score 3):

## Vim, 38 Bytes

```
i)^[8a-*^[r(9hR^_^^[Yo| Welcome User! |^[p
```

Shoutout to the homies in the comments

Original:

```
i)-\*^[vhyl2pa^_^\*-^[vhyl2pa(^[Vyo| Welcome User! |^[p
```

Where `^[` is the `ESC` key

Comment: `i)-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(^]` is much shorter for constructing the top line. Also, `Y` is equivalent to `Vy`

Comment: Actually if you more or less borrow DJ's V answer top line construction you can save 2 bytes on the hardcode input `i)^]8a-*^[r(9hR^_^^[`

Comment: Thanks y'all. I've been using Vim for like a month and I was just trying to see if I could do it. Obviously I have a lot of optimization to go on my workflow

Comment: One last tip: If duplicate the line before opening a newline for "Welcome User!", you won't need to hit `^[` at the end. `YPo| Welcome User! |`

Comment: See? didn't even know that `P` was a thing. That's awesome though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Sed, 51

Two for the price of one:

```
s/^/)-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(/p
x
s/^/| Welcome User! |/p
x
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K05N@f@/WD9OX1NXCwTj4uPAtK6GfgFXBRdIpkYhPDUnOT83VSG0OLVIUaEGJPP/PwA).

```
s/^/)-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(\n| Welcome User! |/p
s/\n.*//
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K05N@f@/WD9OX1NXCwTj4uPAtK5GTF6NQnhqTnJ@bqpCaHFqkaJCjX4BV7F@TJ6elr7@//8A).

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB / Octave, 53 bytes

```
a=')-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(';disp([a;'| Welcome User! |';a])
```

Comment: Why `MATLAB / Python`? This is definitely not valid python.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Sorry I meant Octave. Thanks for noticing the typo. Been answering python questions over on SO all day so brain had a small glitch :)

Comment: If you ommit `disp` Matlab will show leading `ans = \n`.

Comment: @Crowley That's why you need the `disp` there as it won't conform to the exact output.

Comment: If the `ans = ` is not disallowed you can save 6 bytes.

Comment: @Crowley I agree completely with the byte count, but I don't think it's permitted for this challenge.  This is Kolmogorov Complexity so the output must **exactly match** the challenge.  If the OP has some leeway, it would have been mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

## [Carrot](https://github.com/kritixilithos/Carrot/), 51 bytes

```
)-*-*-*\^_\^*-*-*-(
^*1//.+/gS"
| Welcome User! |
"
```

[Try it online!](http://kritixilithos.github.io/Carrot/)

#### Explanation

```
)-*-*-*\^_\^*-*-*-(
^                            Give the stack-string this value ")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(\n"
 *1                          Append 1 duplicate of the stack-string to itself
                             stack-string: ")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(\n)-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-("
//.+/g                       Get matches of /.+/g and set the stack-array to this result
                             stack-array: [")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(",")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-("]
S"
| Welcome User! |
"                            Join the stack-array on "\n| Welcome User! |\n" and
                             set the stack-string to this result
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 50 bytes

```php
<?=$a=")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(","
| Welcome User! |
$a";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WJdFWSVNXCwTj4uPAtK6Gko4SV41CeGpOcn5uqkJocWqRokINl0qikvX//wA)

Comment: `<?=$a=")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(","\n| Welcome User! |\n$a";`

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 52 bytes

```
Column@{t=")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(","| Welcome User! |",t}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 49 bytes

```ruby
$><<[")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-("]*2*"
| Welcome User! |
"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X8XOxiZaSVNXCwTj4uPAtK6GUqyWkZYSV41CeGpOcn5uqkJocWqRokINl9L//wA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Minecraft Functions](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Function), 77 bytes

```
tellraw @a {"text":")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(\n| Welcome User! |\n)-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-("}
```

Comment: This isn't even trying to compress the string...

Comment: @Okx Well try doing that when the only non-constant things you can print are numbers and block/item names :p

Answer (score 2):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 27 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
↑αMΟ±.○h+‘╬1"→ū↑, ¶‘θ⁾@∑32ž
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUyMTkxJXUwM0IxTSV1MDM5RiVCMS4ldTI1Q0JoKyV1MjAxOCV1MjU2QzElMjIldTIxOTIldTAxNkIldTIxOTElMkMlMjAlQjYldTIwMTgldTAzQjgldTIwN0VAJXUyMjExMzIldTAxN0U_)
I have no idea why I still haven't added a capitalize 1st letter of each word function... Here it uses a 4-byte replacement

Answer (score 2):

## Batch, 70 bytes

```
@SET b=@ECHO )-*-*-*^^^^_^^^^*-*-*-(
%b%
@ECHO ^| Welcome User! ^|
%b%
```

I mostly enjoy this one because all the escape characters make the emoticon `^_^` look like an adorable Lovecraft abomination `^^^^_^^^^`

Answer (score 2):

## C, <strike>65</strike> 66 bytes

```
main(){printf("%s| Welcome User! |\n%1$s",")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(\n");}
```

Yes, there are other C solutions, also coming in at about 66 bytes.

Ungolfed

```
main()
{
    printf("%s| Welcome User! |\n%1$s",
          ")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(\n"
          );
}
```

GCC produces a warning for the missing printf prototype.

The %1$s says use argument 1 (again) for the second string argument.

In real-life programs, it can also be used to pass in precision/width arguments into a printf. This avoids having to use a printf to create the format string for the real printf.

Comment: Which compiler successfully compiles and runs this? My `gcc` (7.1.1) gives an error for the missing semicolon and fails to compile.

Comment: csm@localhost:~$ gcc --version

    gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2 

    Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: I tried compiling gcc 4.9.2 from source on my machine, but I still got an error rather than a warning for the missing semicolon. Is there any other way to reproduce this?

Comment: Argh. You are right, the semicolon is needed. I was accidentally running the previous compilation result.

Answer (score 2):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 48 bytes

```
")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-("!&@"
| Welcome User! |
"@19&@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/9fSVNXCwTj4uPAtK6GkqKagxJXjUJ4ak5yfm6qQmhxapGiQg2XkoOhpZrD//8A)

### Explanation

```
")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-("        push the string ")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(" as characters
                   !&@     print all the characters on the stack without popping
                      "
| Welcome User! |          push the string "\n| Welcome User! |\n"
"
 @19                       pop and print 19 characters on the stack
    &@                     print all the characters on the stack
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 62 bytes

```
x->"".format("%s| Welcome User! |\n%<s",")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(\n")
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##LY5BasMwEEX3PsWvwCCF2hdI2xskXZSQRdwEWVGCXHlkrHFIaHJ2R27NwB9mPjxeoy@6CJ2l5vgzGq9jxEo7@s0AR2z7kzYW6@kEvrh3dIaRn3VjDeOqlun/yFJE1uwM1iC8Y7wWH0KUp9C3mqXI4x1b601oLTbR9i@4V5S/RfEqVLGYZn/Y/@1CViTUuJyI3VD7RJzBl@COaJOY/JfYfUOr2eoW2bZlGLjsUsWSSiNp8F7Neo/xCQ)

Or as full program (**110 bytes**):

```
interface A{static void main(String[]a){System.out.printf("%s| Welcome User! |\n%<s",")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(\n");}}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##HchNCsIwEEDhq4yBQiK2F9CNZyjiwloZ0qmkmklJxoK0PXv84S0@eANOWIaReOgeOTsWij1aguOcBMVZmILrwKNjXUt0fL9c0cz1Own5KrykGr9Teq2KtMCZnjZ4glOiuIGl4eKQ1E6ZcvurvbV/S92wMvt1zfkD)

Surprised there wasn't a Java answer yet.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 47 bytes

```powershell
($z=')-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(')
"| Welcome User! |
$z"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0OlylZdU1cLBOPi48C0roa6JpdSjUJ4ak5yfm6qQmhxapGiQg2XSpXS//8A)

Ran into the problem everyone else is running into: there's not enough meat to justify trying to encode the top line's pattern. A fancier join method also turned out to [cost one more byte](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0ddU1cLBOPi48C0roa6lpFuVn5mnjpXjUJ4ak5yfm6qQmhxapGiQg2X@v//AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `J`, 174 [bits<sup>v1</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 21.75 bytes

```
`)-*-*-*^_`øM:`| ÷… ƛ⁼! |`$
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJKPSIsIiIsImApLSotKi0qXl9gw7hNOmB8IMO34oCmIMab4oG8ISB8YCQiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Most likely golfable.

```
`)-*-*-*^_`                 # literal string
           øM               # flip brackets (`[]()`=>`][)(`) and palindromise
              `| ÷… ƛ⁼! |`  # the compressed string `| Welcome User! |`
             :            $ # put the first string on the top of the stack to wrap it around ^
                            # J flag joins by newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 42 bytes

```
A¶| Welcome User! |¶A
A
)-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fy/HQthqF8NSc5PzcVIXQ4tQiRYWaQ9scuRy5NHW1QDAuPg5M62r8/w8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net), <strike>56</strike> 52 bytes

```
<?=$s=")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(\n","| Welcome User! |\n$s";
```

- 4 bytes saved thanks to [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork)

Comment: `;echo` ──→  `,`

Comment: @manatwork Thanks. I guess you always learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

## bash, 52 bytes

```
f=")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-("
echo "$f
| Welcome User! |
$f"
```

Answer (score 1):

## TCL, <strike>73 bytes</strike> 54 bytes

<s>`set a )-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(
    set b "| Welcome User! |"
    puts " $a\n $b\n $a"`</s>

---

```
puts "[set a )-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(]
| Welcome User! |
$a"
```

Thanks @sergiol for the suggestion!

Comment: Can be golfed down quite a lot: http://rextester.com/GUX27128

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 88 bytes

```
fun main(a:Array<String>){val s=")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(";print("$s\n| Welcome User! |\n$s")}"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 25 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
æu√hy╘£.ÅJnc¡┐ßD.P☻Θ╖>╘rÇ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=9175fb6879d49c2e8f4a6e63adbfe1442e5002e9b73ed47280&i=&a=1)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 64 bytes

```
Fn.new{"1| Welcome User! |
1".replace("1",")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(
")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkFaal6xgq/DfLU8vL7W8WsmwRiE8NSc5PzdVIbQ4tUhRoYbLUEmvKLUgJzE5VUPJUElHSVNXCwTj4uPAtK4Gl5Jm7f/gyuKS1Fy98qLMklQNkKl6yYk5ORqamv8B)

### Explanation

```
Fn.new{                           // New anonymous function
       "1| Welcome User! |
1"                                // Create the string "| Welcome User! |"
  .replace("1",")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(
")}                               // Prepend & append the string ")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 63 bytes

```c
f(){printf("%s| Welcome User! |\n%1$s",")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(\n");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NQ7O6oCgzryRNQ0m1uEYhPDUnOT83VSG0OLVIUaEmJk/VUKVYSUdJU1cLBOPi48C0rkZMnpKmde3/3MTMPKARQGOAHAA)

Three bytes shorter than all the previous solutions because new rules allow functions.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 57 bytes

```cs
Write("{0}\n| Welcome User! |\n{0}",")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(");
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/vCizJFVDqdqgNiavRiE8NSc5PzdVIbQ4tUhRoSYmDyiupKOkqasFgnHxcWBaV0NJ0/r/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>127</s> 107 bytes

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(){std::string a="\n)-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(\n";std::cout<<a;std::cout<<"| Welcome User! |";std::cout<<a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/XzkzLzmnNCVVwSYzv7ikKDUx144rM69EITcxM09Ds7q4JMXKCiiemZeukGirFJOnqasFgnHxcWBaVyMmT8karCo5v7TExiYRmaNUoxCempOcn5uqEFqcWqSoUIOmtvb/fwA)

Lowered to 107 by [noodle man](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/108687/noodle-man)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(){std::string a="\n)-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(\n";std::cout<<a<<"| Welcome User! |"<<a;}
```

Comment: 107 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpBCoMwEADvvmJNL1rIB3TrL8SLWMK6yILZiImn2renVuYwMAxtm12Icn6I0nrMDCghpp2d7wrRBN6JVvUnprlpri66gHuZUWv7/DO9p9u2GtW090XhSIgO0Zww8ErBM/SR9xJOc/X2m/MP "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: Building on @noodleman [99 bytes](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/XzkzLzmnNCXVJjO/uKQoNTHXjiszr0QhNzEzT0OzOrG0JF8h0VYpJk9TVwsE4@LjwLSuRkyeknVxSYqVVXJ@aYmNTaKNjVKNQnhqTnJ@bqpCaHFqkaJCjRJQ3Lr2/38A "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

### [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>76</s> 61 bytes

```
!v"(-*-*-*^_"~! |
 >~")"a"| !resU emocleW |v"61pa10.
l?!;o >
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 55 bytes

```
$a=')-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(';
echo <<<S
$a
| Welcome User! |
$a
S;
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 0):

## VBA, 48 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes no input and outputs a greeting to the user via the immediate window

```vba
a=")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(":?a:?"| Welcome User! |":?a
```

Comment: I post mine then deleted immediately when I saw yours. :D

Answer (score 0):

## Golang, 67 Bytes

```
func n(){a:=")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(\n";Print(a+"| Welcome User! |\n"+a)}
```

Prints with a trailing newline.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8//X5CYnJ2YnqqQm5iZx8WVmVuQX1SioKeglJZbosTFlVaalwyW0tBUqObiBFJctf/BgkBmdaKVrZKmrhYIxsXHgWldjZg8JeuAosy8Eo1EbaUahfDUnOT83FSF0OLUIkWFGqCsdqJm7f//AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 29 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
-*３×^_＋)×│| Welcome User! |┌）
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=LSoldUZGMTMlRDclNUVfJXVGRjBCJTI5JUQ3JXUyNTAyJTdDJTIwV2VsY29tZSUyMFVzZXIlMjElMjAlN0MldTI1MEMldUZGMDk_,v=2)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 58 bytes

```javascript
(u=')-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(')=>[u,'| Welcome User! |',u].join`
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@1@j1FZdU1cLBOPi48C0roa6pq1ddKmOeo1CeGpOcn5uqkJocWqRokKNuk5prF5WfmZeAlfC/@T8vOL8nFS9nPx0jTQNTc3/AA)

I am sure I can golf if down , but later

Answer (score 0):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 46 bytes

```
>")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(":$ak"| Welcome User! |"ak@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/99OSVNXCwTj4uPAtK6GkpVKYrZSjUJ4ak5yfm6qQmhxapGiQo1SYrbD//8A)

It will appear to process until it times out, due to the two `^` commands which spawn IPs that do nothing (necessitating the explicit entry `>`). I am disapointed that this is 2 bytes shorter than the [multiple IP method](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/9/OLjFbSVNXCwTj4uPAtK6GkgMXSLxGITw1Jzk/N1UhtDi1SFGhRsnh/38A). Constructing the first and last lines using multiplication/duplication turns out to be even more expensive as well (50 bytes). :(

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 48 bytes

```powershell
$a=')-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(';$a;"| Welcome User! |";$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyXRVl1TVwsE4@LjwLSuhrq1SqK1Uo1CeGpOcn5uqkJocWqRokKNElD4/38A)

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 54 bytes

```powershell
$a=')-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(';write $a;"| Welcome User! |";$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyXRVl1TVwsE4@LjwLSuhrp1eVFmSaqCSqK1Uo1CeGpOcn5uqkJocWqRokKNkrVK4v//AA)

#### Old - 68 bytes

```powershell
Write-Host ")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(`n| Welcome User! |`n)-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-("
```

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 61 bytes

```r
r=")-*-*-*^_^*-*-*-(\n";cat(r,"| Welcome User! |\n",r,sep="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8hWSVNXCwTj4uPAtK5GTJ6SdXJiiUaRjlKNQnhqTnJ@bqpCaHFqkaJCDVBOp0inOLXAVklJ8/9/AA)

Has a trailing newline. I couldn't see if that was approved or not, so I just rolled with it.